# Typo3 mailserver issues (Mailing list hitobito CRM)

Tags: configuration, typo3, office365, mail-server

We from the the Swiss umbrella association for youth parliaments (DSJ) use TYPO3 as the backbone of our website. Next to TYPO3, we also use the CRM software hitobito, which allows us to create "Abos" with "mailing lists". However, this service is currently not working since Hitobito has recently changed its mail server. I have already changed the server addresses manually in our 365 Admin microsoft account and the changes have been verified by the Hitobito support.

This is where TYPO3 comes into play. The support staff from Hitobito suspects that the mail server configurations must also be changed in TYPO3. I, as a layman, have no clue where to make such changes, however. I was hoping you could help me out here. I believe the following information must be updated in the TYPO3 configuration:

*For the new mail server:

crm.dsj.ch IN MX 10 app.hitobito.ch.

For the outgoing mail server:

crm.dsj.ch 3600 IN TXT "v=spf1 a:mxout.appuio.ch -all*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you gave has nothing to do with TYPO3 but is part of the domain record. You should approach your domain registrar (seems to be https://www.visol.ch/ according to whois) with that.

The 1st one is to designate the mail server `app.hitobito.ch` for all incoming mail to recipients `...@crm.dsj.ch` (so-called `MX` record).

And the 2nd one is to lower the spam level for outgoing mails from senders `...@crm.dsj.ch` from the server `mxout.appuio.ch` (so-called `SPF`).

Is your webserver supposed to send mails, too? If so and you have problems with receiving these mails, I suggest to use the InstallTool's "test mail" function and send a mail to https://www.mail-tester.com/ - a great tool to identify spam-related problems.

Comment: Dear Jonas

Thanks for the tip with the mail-tester. I can use it for another purpose I think ;). Yes that one support guy also said something about visol, so this is certainly the right track.

Have a nice day!